# Is the coding of the CSS incorrect?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have created a simple responsive login form. That allows the user to log-in and reset password. When filling out the username/password fields, both of these fields are mixed together and not on seperate lines. I have checked to see if the CSS layout was correct but I cannot seem to find a reason as to why the username and password fields do this.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: url(backgroundTwo.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.login {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 380px;
  padding: 80px 40px 40px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.form::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
  border-radius: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.form img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 100px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.form h2 {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  color: #ff652f;
}

.form .input input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: indianred;
}

.form .input label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .3s ease-out;
}

.form .input input:focus+label .form .input input:valid+label {
  transform: translateY(-18px);
  color: #ff652f;
  font-size: .8rem;
}

.submit-button {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #ff652f;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.forgot-password {
  color: inherit;
}

#forgot-password {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

#forgot-password:target {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.5rem;
  top: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="LoginTwo.css">
  <title>LoginFormTwo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="login">
    <form action="" class="form">
      <img src="avatarTwo.jpg" alt="">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text" name="loginUser" id="loginUser">
        <label for="loginUser">User Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input">
        <input type="password" name="loginPassword" id="loginPassword">
        <label for="loginPassword">password</label>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="login" class="submit-button">
      <a href="#forgot-password" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
    </form>

    <div id="forgot-password">
      <form action="" class="form">
        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
        <h2>Reset Password</h2>
        <div class="input">
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
          <label for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that I have to set to postion to relative and not absolute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see here is that you didn't set a `position: relative;` to the `<div>` with class `.input`.
Since you set a `position: absolute;` to the `label`, its positioning is calculated from the closest parent with a `position: relative;` set. In your case, it's the `<form>` with class `.form`

Try adding these changes:

```css
.form .input {
   position: relative;
}
```

and adjust the `top` property of the `label`:

```css
.form .input label {
  top: -30px;
}
```

Here's a working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/rNxWBWM)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's because your form is set to absolute so your labels are relative to the form.

By putting `top: 0;` your labels will be on top of the form. You can fix this by changing the .input position to relative like so:

```
.input {
  position: relative;
}
```

And you can change the labels position by modifying the top value

```
.form .input label {   
    top: -25px /*or any value you want*/ 
}
```